# React type error cannot read properties of array, error calling it null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state, typeerror

[Code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARTLu.png)

so `{this.state.setCity};` includes weather info if I `console.log(this.state.setCity);` it gives me the array of weather of the city but if i `console.log({this.state.setCity.main.temp})` it gives me this error saying its "null". even though it prints out the temperature on the console.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wn2SS.png)

The image for `console.log({this.state.setCity})`
[Console.log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUaYa.png)

Comment: You can't call `.main` on an array can you provide the log for `this.state.setCity`?

Comment: Console.log(this.state.setCity}) imge uploaded please check

Comment: My bad i didn't see, your error is because you're calling main when this.state.setCity is null, you're setState is asynchronous and will be set on next renderer. 
Try to put your console.log in the body of your render() like this `console.log(this.state.setCity?.main?.temp)` this should print null first and then your value without error

Answer (score 1):

Your state needs some time to mutate, and since the code executes console.log({this.state.setCity.main.temp}) before the state mutates, you get the previous value which is empty. Although the console output runs on your screen as it gets initiated as undefined before the state mutates, then appends the value.

Basically, `setState` is asynchronous. It means you can’t call it on one line and assume the state has changed on the next.

You can read more on setstate here on the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)